# MS Word crashes after ListTemplate applied

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm using Excel 2010 VBA to programmatically generate a Word 2010 document.
The program crashes when I attempt to apply a ListTemplate to one of the paragraphs I've inserted (Line 5 in the code below).

```
thisValue = tempSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
.Content.InsertAfter thisValue
.Content.InsertParagraphAfter
Set thisRange = .Paragraphs(i).Range
thisRange.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate ListTemplate:=ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1)
```

The error thrown is shown below:

> Run-time error "-2147023170 (800706be)"
>   Automation Error
>   The remote procedure call failed.

The entire procedure:

```
Sub MoveDataToWord(ByRef tempSheet As Worksheet)

Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wrdApp.Visible = True
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add
With wrdDoc
    For i = 1 To tempSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        thisValue = tempSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
        .Content.InsertAfter thisValue
        .Content.InsertParagraphAfter
        Set thisRange = .Paragraphs(i).Range
        thisRange.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate ListTemplate:=ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1)
    Next i
End With
Set wrdDoc = Nothing
Set wrdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you late binding or early binding with word? If you are using late binding then try and replace `wdBulletGallery` with `1` and then try again.

Comment: Not sure if I'm late or early binding, I'm calling from Excel. Regardless, I tested it with 1 instead and received the same error.

Comment: The syntax of the code is correct. Can I see the complete procedure?

Comment: I updated the original posting to include the procedure.

Comment: The first time I ran it. It worked and the 2nd time it didn't. So I checked MSDN and this is what I found http://support.microsoft.com/kb/189618

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListGalleries is an object within the Word Application. To access it, I needed to use wrdApp.ListGalleries. The fixed line of code is show below.

```
thisRange.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate ListTemplate:=wrdApp.ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1)
```